# Can other users get access to python script running inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm making a device based on raspberry pi. The docker environment is set following docker setup instruction and is running under rootless mode. I have an admin user that belongs to docker user group and put docker files, python scripts etc in this admin user's home folder and then run docker compose to setup all the containers. So the docker service will ran every time when device is powerd on. Only I can use this admin user account

Another user account is setup which doesn't have access to admin user's home folder and doesn't belong to the docker user group. This account is used by all other people and the rpi was booted to this user by default.

My question is would other people be able to get access to the python scripts running in the docker container?

I guess the answer is no since they don't have access to the admin account?
I need to figure out a way so that my device won't be easily hacked by others(getting my source code).

Cheers

Comment: Indeed that's an option. I have three scripts running a web app and other functions. It might take a lot effort to compile them and debug etc. I guess. If others cannot get access to the source code. Then I can ship the device to a customer now. @CherryDT

Comment: @CherryDT You cannot compile to a .pyc for safety. I'd reverse it in a couple of minutes at worst. Bytecode is _not_ obfuscation. All of your python code is accessible in a docker container

Comment: @roganjosh, do you know how to access python code in docker container? If I log in using normal user account, I can't access docker service.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but if you can run the container, you almost certainly can get access to the code layers

Comment: (a) It's almost trivial to `docker cp` the source files out, or `docker run` an interactive shell to browse around; (b) anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can very easily take over the entire host.  If protecting the source code is important to you, using a compiled language (Go, Rust, C++, ...) that doesn't force you to distribute it is probably a key requirement.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze. I will try to compile it first. Does it mean that the code is safe if other users cannot use docker command? Or they still have other ways to get access to the container?

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you. I will try to compile it first